# Finding letters in a word that have different orders

Tags: prolog

Here is a description of a prolog program that I am working on:

user might enter a 5 letter word, and the only letters allowed are a,b,c,d,e. He may not enter all words, so he may enter something like userWord(A,b,C,d,E) - so only b and d are filled in. These letters may be entered in any order. I have to make this work without using lists or functions and using only grounded facts.

This is what I have:

```
values(a,b,c,d,e).

userWord(U,W,X,Y,Z):-
    values(A1,A2,A3,A4,A5),
    findletters(U,W,X,Y,Z,A1,A2,A3,A4,A5).   % U-Z are outputs and A1-A5 are inputs


findletters(A1,A2,A3,A4,A5,A1,A2,A3,A4,A5):-
    findletters(A2,A1,A3,A4,A5,A1,A2,A3,A4,A5).
```

I need to have findletters that changes orders of letters, until it finds a good match. Of course, I may need several findletters that change the order in different ways. But what I can't seem to get, is how to

1. call findletters with possible values
2. make it remember values are only a,b,c,d,e
3. make it take the last order it generated (which failed) and work on that and change the orders until it finds a good match.

Any assistance is extremely appreciated

Comment: Without using lists? That's just plain sadistic! I had a beautiful solution until I read your requrements again and noticed this.

Answer (score 0):

Break your predicates down further, use `letter(a). letter(b). ... letter(e).` This will help to find that only valid letters were entered.

Maybe use it like so:

```
userWord(A,B,C,D,E) :-
    letter(A), letter(B), ...,letter(E), /* this will fail here on 
                                            non-valid letter */
    .... /* if it gets here the letters form a valid(?) word */
```

Alternatively, if you feel like typing, you can add facts for all the combinations of 'abcde' :) or you can let prolog generate it: `word(AA,BB,CC,DD,EE):- letter(AA), ..., letter(EE).`This will generate 'words' like 'aaaaa' which may not be what you want, in which case you need to add: `AA!=BB,AA!=CC,...,DD!=EE.` to the word()-clause.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I forgot to mention that values are distinct, but since I do not want to use functions (including !=, + ,is, etc) or negation I am not sure how to make word(AA,BB,CC,DD,EE) generate distinct elements. It would not be possible to list all facts and various orders either.

Comment: @Amalia A: The limitations you set are nonsensical; you should use the facilities of the language, those you mention are built-in, not from some added library. Anyway I may be misunderstanding your problem altogether, so when you do solve it, please post the solution so I, and others can learn ;)

Comment: On second thought, your problem would seem to have become how to simulate '!=' ?

Comment: Well, I think the most important part for me is to figure out how to change positions of variables to generate new orders and test them against the word. I wonder if you (or anyone reading this comment) is familiar with such a technique in Prolog????????? Most appreciate any replies.

Answer (score 0):

```
values(a,b,c,d,e).


userWord(A,B,C,D,E):-
    values(A,B,C,D,E).
userWord(A,B,C,D,E):-
    reArr(A,B,F,G),reArr(B,C,H,I),reArr(C,D,J,K),reArr(D,E,L,M).
    userWord(F,G,I,K,M).

reArr(X,Y,X,Y):-X<Y.            %For this check the variables must be bound and must be converted into ASCII code..
reArr(X,Y,X,Y):-reArr(Y,X,Y,X).
```

I think the above logic would help you... Try and post your success code..

Thanks,
Cling :)

Answer (score 0):

This could be pointless, but your task can be solved with just a call:

```
userWord(A,B,C,D,E) :- permutation([a,b,c,d,e], [A,B,C,D,E]).
```

Permuting 5 distinct values requires 120 facts.

It's not reasonable to do that by hand. If you are allowed to *cheat*, then use permutation/2 to generate all facts, and assert them, or write to a Prolog file, to be consulted.

I'm sorry I don't know any simpler algorithm than permutation/2, and I'm looking forward to see if such algorithm or some interesting trick exists.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it's easier than I thought.

```
letter(a).
letter(b).
letter(c).
letter(d).
letter(e).

userword(V, W, X, Y, Z) :-
  letter(V),
  letter(W),
  letter(X),
  letter(Y),
  letter(Z),
  V \= W,
  V \= X,
  V \= Y,
  V \= Z,
  W \= X,
  W \= Y,
  W \= Z,
  X \= Y,
  X \= Z,
  Y \= Z.
```

We want all letters in a userword to be, well, letters. We also need them to be unique. That's all.